# Is OpenAI Gym CartPole-v0 200th step interruption unfair to agent?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

This OpenAI [environment](https://gym.openai.com/envs/CartPole-v0) provides an agent only with positions and speeds, so an agent can't tell apart good state in the beginning (upright pole, low speed) which should have high value and a good state (upright pole, low speed) near the end (200th step), which, to the horror and confusion of an agent, actually has very low expected reward due to environment imminently shutting down.

I wonder how much this can affect common reinforcement algorithms.

P.S.

I've implemented Experience Replay into my (very simple) DQN algorithm and it seems, that ignoring steps with time >150 in training actually works better. However, performance of an algorithm is very noisy, so I need more experiments on this.

Also, I've stumbled upon this [environment](https://gym.openai.com/envs/OffSwitchCartpole-v0), which seems related to the problem. Safe (in "paper-clip-maximizer" sense) AI should be indifferent to turning off.